# React - Implement a file upload component using Mui

Tags: reactjs, file, material-ui

I am trying to build a file upload component. Earlier I did use `<input type="file">` but I have very little space to accomodate the input type and within the litle space, I have to display "Choose file" and the total file path. When I decrease the width, the component display is not too elegant to see.

This was my earlier code:

```
 <label id="licensefile">
          LicenseFile
          <input            
            type="file"
            name="personalLicense"
            className={styles.personallicense}
          />
        </label>
```

My CSS :

```
.personallicense{

    position: absolute;
    top: 78px;
    left:250px;
    width:50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}

input[name="personalLicense"] {
    width: 30px;
  }
```

I have been looking for alternate using Mui

I want to build something like this:

```
import FileUploadOutlined from "@mui/icons-material/FileUploadOutlined";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

<label >
        License
        <TextField
          variant="standard"      
         
          type="text"
         
          InputProps={{
            endAdornment: (
              <FileUploadOutlined
                onClick={() => {
                  handleUpload();
                }}
              >                
              </FileUploadOutlined>
            ),
          }}
        />
      </label>
```

How to invoke the file upload from the Mui thing similar to input type "file"

The total space to accomodate this component is almost 50 to 60 px. I cannot adjust more than that as it is an existing compoenent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got answer from other source but posting here for any future references:

```
<TextField
      variant="standard"          
      type="text"
      InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
          <IconButton component="label">
            <FileUploadOutlined />
            <input
              styles={{display:"none"}}
              type="file"
              hidden
              onChange={handleUpload}
              name="[licenseFile]"
            />
          </IconButton>
        ),
      }}
    />
```